# Symfony 3.0 Form Posting

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.0 form builder. I'm having an issue when posting data where I'm getting a cannot reverseTransform since the data been posted doesn't match. Now, the reason why I'm assuming this is happening, is that the data was saved to the database with lots of \r\n that can be at the end, or beginning and between lines to create paragraphs and can be just one \r\n or multiple. These texts are used as a value of options from a select. I think Symfony is "trimming" and probably doing some extra steps to make sure the data goes into the database how it should.

I started looking through Symfony form classes while debugging and I saw it does some regex and trim when posting the data per field. But, I tried using that to try to match the data coming from db so that the value matches the value of the field when form posts, but have been unsuccessful. Basically, I need to find a way to make sure I clean the data to match what Symfony will compare against before I set it on the select option.

Do you guys know exactly how Symfony is "trimming" the data when posted? Just want to do the same process so that the data matches when posting. I would prefer to do this on the data itself on the database but, currently some PHP code to match what Symfony is doing would be great.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT 1**
Forgot to mention that there might be other characters/escape sequences like form feed \f etc. This comes from copy/paste users have done when saving data,

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to fix this. So, using Symfony\Component\Form\Util\StringUtil class's trim method, I wrapped my option value around it, and when it posts, it does the same as Symfony does so the values match now. Where I failed (I tried this before) was that I was doing this on part of the option value instead of the whole value thinking only the part I was trying to fix was the issue, but it wasn't just that. Everything is fine now.

Answering just in case someone in the future runs into a similar problem.